# How to keep data of a **double?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, double, access-violation

Let say I've a class that got a double pointer of pointer member:

```
public:
    double **pSamples;
```

inside a member class function, at some times, I populate this "matrix", using RAII idiom:

```
void LoadWave() {
    vector<vector<double>> samplesContainer(mWaveNumChannels, vector<double>(mWaveReader.GetSize()));
    vector<double*> ptrs(mWaveNumChannels);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != mWaveNumChannels; ++i) {
        ptrs[i] = samplesContainer[i].data();
    }

    pWaveSamples = ptrs.data();
    mWaveReader.ReadDoublesNI(pWaveSamples, 0, mWaveReader.GetSize());
}
```

All is ok! But now, if later on another function I try to iterate/manage this pointer of pointer, I got an Access Violation.

I think because vector release/destroy when LoadWave() ends right?

How would you keep so the data/matrix? So I can re-use it later?

Comment: This is not RAII. If it were RAII, the array would be allocated in the object's constructors, destroyed in the object's destructor, and appropriately managed in the assignment operator; instead of some random function somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Please update your code, your population code currently doesn't populate `pSamples`.

Comment: make `ptrs` and `samplesContainer` be class members, but not `pSamples`

Comment: I want to work with pSamples, not STL.

Comment: @paizza Why? A pointer to pointers is *not* a container. It's not a container view either. `pSamples` neither owns any data, nor knows the size of the array of data it is supposed to be observing. Please, use proper semantics: if `pSamples` should own the lifetime of its data, use `std::vector` or some other RAII container. If `pSamples` should just iterate over data owned externally, then make `pSamples` a proper "pointer and size" structure like `gsl::span` and make sure the data outlives `pSamples`

Comment: @KABoissonneault I'm working with audio at lower level. I need the faster way to manage a sequence of samples. I guess there's nothing faster than pointer and double?

Comment: @paizza Do you have proof `std::vector` is slower? By design, unless you use `push_back` and `insert` a lot, `std::vector` will do only the same operations as the ones you would write manually: `new[]`, iterate from `begin()` to `end()`, then `delete[]` when appropriate. The data in `std::vector` is guaranteed to be continuous, which means it is cache-friendly and the basically the most efficient way to own data. If your code is any "faster" than that, then it is probably doing something incorrect, like leaking responsibilities

Comment: All the framework I'm using use just pure double* and double**, so I also guess would be better to stay in the same "context". Else I would switch repeatedly between one and another.

Comment: @paizza No need to switch for those, because `T* std::vector<T>::data()" returns the underlying buffer just as if you had been using, for example, `double*` all along. When you call a function from your framework that expects a `double*` and a `size_t` size, just call `pSamples.data()` and `pSamples.size()`. This way, you won't make mistakes like you did in your question (because of proper RAII), and your code will be just as performant (no pointless copies)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114845/discussion-between-paizza-and-kaboissonneault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate a dangling pointer, which, of course, results in an access violation. The C++ solution is to avoid raw pointers, but let the memory be managed by some method, ideally using a standard-library container.

One lazy method is

```
class myclass 
{
  std::vector<double > samplesContainer;
  std::vector<double*> samples;
  void setPter(std::size_t num_samples, std::size_t smaple_size)
  {
    samplesContainer.resize(num_samples*smaple_size);
    samples.resize(num_samples)
    for(std::size_t n=0; n!=num_samples, ++n)
      samples[n] = &(samplesContainer[n*smaple_size])
  }
  const double**psample() const { return samples.data(); }
  /* ... */
};
```

Though a 2D array adaption of a 1D vector (which will not need/provide a `double**`) is rather simple to implement.

From your comments, I suspect that the frame work you're using is not C++ or is poorly written: a good C++ interface wouldn't use `double**` (or even `double*`), regardless of efficiency considerations.

Comment: Good answer, but that last comment is arguable: if a library wants to be as "generic" as possible without incurring the compilation time and "readibility" cost of templates, it should have "pointer and size" arguments (or the equivalent `array_view` abstraction) instead of a specific container (ex: `std::vector`), otherwise the clients will be forced to commit to use or at least convert to a specific type, which is a pointless restriction and/or runtime-cost.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes, but that can be done w/o `double**`, `double*` and `size_t` is sufficient.